# T-SQL: Two Level Aggregation in Same Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that joins a master and a detail table. Master table records are duplicated in results as expected. I get aggregation on detail table an it works fine. But I also need another aggregation on master table at the same time. But as master table is duplicated, aggregation results are duplicated too.

I want to demonstrate this situation as below;

```
    If Object_Id('tempdb..#data') Is Not Null Drop Table #data
    Create Table #data (Id int, GroupId int, Value int)

    If Object_Id('tempdb..#groups') Is Not Null Drop Table #groups
    Create Table #groups (Id int, Value int)

    /* insert groups */
    Insert #groups (Id, Value)
    Values  (1,100), (2,200), (3, 200)


    /* insert data */
    Insert #data (Id, GroupId, Value)
    Values  (1,1,10),
            (2,1,20),
            (3,2,50),
            (4,2,60),
            (5,2,70),
            (6,3,90)
```

My select query is

```
Select  Sum(data.Value) As Data_Value,
        Sum(groups.Value) As Group_Value
From    #data data
        Inner Join #groups groups On groups.Id = data.GroupId
```

The result is;

```
Data_Value  Group_Value
300         1000
```

Expected result is;

```
Data_Value  Group_Value
300         500
```

Please note that, derived table or sub-query is not an option. Also `Sum(Distinct groups.Value)` is not suitable for my case.

Comment: It can't be done without a derived table or subquery. Why is this not an option?

Comment: can another query be wrapped around a modified version of the current query without subqueries?

Comment: @GarethD my table is too big and subquery will cost a lot of resources.

Comment: @Bohemian In fact I wonder if there is a way to do this by some new windowing function or something like that.

Comment: If that is your reasoning, I suspect you do not understand how subqueries work internally. SQL is a declarative language, you tell it what you want it to do, not how to do it. There is a pretty good chance any hack that you can come up with to do this is going to be more expensive than just using a derived table. Have you tried it with subqueries? Do you actually have a performance issue? If so you should look into trying to add indexes, or use sargable predicates rather than trying to rewrite your query without derived tables.

Comment: That is the correct expected result. It is not your desired results. And a lot of rules around what you cannot use.  Too bad because I think you can do this efficiently with a derived table.      http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Decoded it can be done without using a subquery with your "complex" query, but you need *your* query itself to be a subquery. Would that work?

Comment: @Frisbee I am not sure if this is a XY problem. My desired result is clear(or I think so). The X is only an example

Comment: Then you don't get XY.   Desired result not restricted how.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        (
          Select  Sum(d.Value) From    #data d
          WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #groups WHERE Id = d.GroupId )
         ) AS Data_Value
       ,(
          SELECT Sum( g.Value)  FROM #groups g
          WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #data WHERE GroupId = g.Id)
         ) AS Group_Value
```

Comment: SUM(Distinct) is not option because there are group records that has same value

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you just want to sum value column of both table and show it in a single row. in that case you don't need to join those just select the sum as a column like :

```
SELECT  (SELECT SUM(VALUE) AS Data_Value FROM #DATA), 
        (SELECT SUM(VALUE) AS Group_Value FROM #groups)
```

Comment: I have tried to simply demonstrate this situation in my exapmle. But in fact my query is very complex and I can not use sub-queries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking for. But it seems like you want the value from one group and the collected value that represents a group in the data table.
In that case I would suggest something like this.

```
select Sum(t.Data_Value) as Data_Value, Sum(t.Group_Value) as Group_Value
from
(select Sum(data.Value) As Data_Value, groups.Value As Group_Value
from data 
inner join groups on groups.Id = data.GroupId
group by groups.Id, groups.Value) 
as t
```

The edit should do the trick for you.

Comment: thanks but I can not group by `groups.Value` field. I need a single row result in this example

Comment: @Decoded - Was this edit what you were looking for. If not, I'm afraid I won't be able to assist you.